# make existing rdesktop session grab keyboard/mouse

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, remote-desktop, rdesktop

By default, `rdesktop` grabs keyboard, so that key combinations such as <kbd>Alt+Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Alt+F4</kbd> act inside the rdesktop window. This can be overridden with the `-K` option

```
rdesktop -K myserver.mydomain.com
```

Is there any way to chage this during an existing session? I always connect using the `-K` option, but sometimes I would like to switch so that rdesktop grabs my keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `CTL+ALT+ENTER` to leave full-screen mode. Then you can select a host window from the task bar, or minimize the `rdesktop` window. As long as the `rdesktop` window doesn't have focus, it won't capture keyboard events.

Unfortunately, this doesn't appear to simply release the keyboard, the same way `right-ctrl` would in Remmina or VirtualBox.